# torch assign not in place by tensor slicing in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to convert my current code, which assigns tensors in place, to an outer operation.
Meaning currently the code is

```
self.X[:, nc:] = D
```

Where D is in the same shape as `self.X[:, nc:]`
But I would like to convert it to

```
sliced_index = ~ somehow create an indexed tensor from self.X[:, nc:]
self.X = self.X.scatter(1,sliced_index,mm(S_, Z[:, :n - nc]))
```

And don't know how to create that index mask tensor that represents only the entries in the sliced tensor

Minimal example:

```
a = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
D = [[6],[7]]
Not_in_place = [[0,1,6],[3,4,7]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A masked scatter is a little easier. The mask itself can be computed as an in-place operation after which you can use `masked_scatter`

```
mask = torch.zeros(self.X.shape, device=self.X.device, dtype=torch.bool)
mask[:, nc:] = True
self.X = self.X.masked_scatter(mask, D)
```

A more specialized version which relies on broadcasting but should be more efficient would be

```
mask = torch.zeros([1, self.X.size(1)], device=self.X.device, dtype=torch.bool)
mask[0, nc:] = True
self.X = self.X.masked_scatter(mask, D)
```

Comment: Yes, haha that also replies another post I published, didn't think about that thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Tensor.clone`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.clone) to copy tensor.

```py
a = torch.tensor([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
D = torch.tensor([[6],[7]])

n, n[:,-1:] = a.clone(), D
n
tensor([[0, 1, 6],
        [3, 4, 7]])
a
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: This method still uses assignment, which I want to avoid because of the backward step involved (that doesn't allow self-assignment)

Comment: then try this `a.clone().detach()`

Comment: With detach you lose the gradients completely